# Batch Help: Removing Characters from a Variable with number inputs

Tags: variables, batch-file, character

*Is it possible to input the amount of characters to remove from the beginning and the end of a variable using other pre-defined variables? or did i just make a code mistake? because i've tried something like this:*

```
@echo off
CLS
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
set /p "word=Enter a Word> "
echo.
set /p "numb1=Suffix Amount Removed> "
echo.
set /p "numb2=Prefix Amount Removed> "
echo.
set new=%word:~!numb1!,-!numb2!%
echo.
echo  Before: !word!
echo.
echo  After: !new!
echo.
pause >nul
exit
```

*And instead of removing characters from the beginning and end of the batch with a pre defined variable, for example if input `3` for* `numb1` *and* `numb2` *when it echo's* `!new!` *instead of removing the characters it shows* `After: word:~3,-3`  *Some help would be appreciated please, and thanks for anyone who does help.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
CLS
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
set /p "word=Enter a Word> "
echo.
set /p "numb1=Suffix Amount Removed> "
echo.
set /p "numb2=Prefix Amount Removed> "
echo.
set new=!word:~%numb1%,-%numb2%!
echo.
echo  Before: !word!
echo.
echo  After: !new!
echo.
pause >nul
exit
```